# Wildcard * not matching headers element in RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, http, rest

I need to pass a token variable through an HTTP Header, so that I can process it within the method it calls. I am using a wildcard[1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers%28%29) for this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, headers = {"Accept=application/json","Token=*"})
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteFromJson(@PathVariable("id") Integer id , @RequestHeader("Token") String token) {
}
```

It happens that whenever I send any header like "Token: 123", it is ignored by the application and does not enter the method. It only enters it when I send the header "Token: *" just exactly as defined, thus ignoring the wildcard.

Any ideas on what can go wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the javadoc states

> Also supports **media type** wildcards (*), for headers such as Accept
>   and Content-Type.

You can't use it for others.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that must be it, I will try with those. Could somebody please suggest some proper quickfix or better workaround for this? Considering the http method must be Delete, and there needs to be some simple form of validation before deleting.

Comment: If the `Token` header can be anything, but it has to be there, just use `"Token"`, with no value equality.

Comment: well, the fact is that only the owner of the resource should be able to delete it, so here I am trying to pass a previously generated (and stored) token to validate the action

Comment: @user8658912 Note that the `@RequestMapping` isn't for validation, but declares rules for dispatching. You can do the validation yourself in an interceptor or in the handler method itself.